# Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 9408 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 2352 bytes

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, bytebuffer

I have a problem with input data for a TensorFlow Lite in **Android**. 
I trained a keras model using LeNet with python and next converted to .tflite
I visualized a .tflite model with Netron to be sure that input size is: **28x28x3** (2352).

Afterwards I wanted to run this model on Android using TensorFlowLite libraries. 
But I've got this error:

> Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 9408 bytes and a
>   ByteBuffer with 2352 bytes.

When I multiplied ByteBuffer size by 4, -> 28x28x3x4 - there was not a problem but unfortunately the prediction result was not correct. It always shows values: 1.0 or 0.0 or NaN.

Could someone help me to solve this problem? I'm facing this issue from few days and couldn't find solution for custom .tflite model.

**EDIT TO PROVIDE A SOLUTION**

I realized that this model is not quantized and due to converting process I needed to increase ByteBuffer size 4 times. In my case I needed:

```
ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2352 * 4)
```

Also during a for loops I needed to divide values by 255.0f:

```
   for (i in 0 until inputSize) {
        for (j in 0 until inputSize) {
            val value = intValues[pixel++]
            byteBuffer.put(((value shr 16 and 0xFF) / 255.0f).toByte())
            byteBuffer.put(((value shr 8 and 0xFF) / 255.0f).toByte())
            byteBuffer.put(((value and 0xFF) / 255.0f).toByte())
        }
    }
```